# Multiline seaborn plot from multiple input files

Tags: python, seaborn

I have generated different dataset files. With python I concatenated them to get a table.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('/path/file1', sep=" ",names=['x', 'density1'], header=None))

df2 = pd.read_csv('/path/file2', sep=" ",names=['x', 'density2'], header=None))
frames = [df1, df2]
result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).reindex(df1.index)
```

[image]

Now I want to produce a multiline plot with seaborn. I tried the following:

```
sns.lineplot(x='x', y=['density1', 'density2'],data=result)
```

It did not work. What is the correct way to plot data from different columns in the same plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is good

```py
df1 = pd.read_csv('/path/file1', sep=" ",names=['x', 'density1'], header=None))

df2 = pd.read_csv('/path/file2', sep=" ",names=['x', 'density2'], header=None))
frames = [df1, df2]
result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).reindex(df1.index)
```

Up until you go here:

```py
sns.lineplot(x='x', y=['density1', 'density2'],data=result)
```

What you want to do instead is call the sns.lineplot argument for each entry you would like plotted as follows:

```py
name_list = ['density1' 'density2']
for entry in df_name_list:
   sns.lineplot(x='x' y=entry, data=result)
```